# Deleted Frostcrap Spire DLC and reloaded a save when in the living quarters. I ended up in a dark area

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

So I played Oblivion and got the Frostcrag Spire and I made a save in the living quarters. Then I accidentaly deleted the DLC because is was in my hard drive deleting saves and stuff and accidentaly deleted the DLC too. Then when I reloaded my save I was in darkness. I noticed there was the inside of a house up ahead, but I can't seem to get to the house. Will someone please help me? The last save was just 5 levels away and had no more due to deleting them in my hard drive.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the dlc?

Comment: This is a know glitch to cheat, you are inside of a house in Bruma if i'm not mistaken. See [this link](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Exploitable_Glitches#Frostcrag_Spire_Glitch) for more information.

Comment: Quit the game without saving, then re-install the DLC.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can bring up the console and type coc testinghall. If it works you will be in a room with lots of doors in front of you and some of them at your back in the manin block. In the doors behind you there is one called Hawk Haven, if you go there you can fast travel to any location in your map.